# How to only show a list box after a certain number of entries

Tags: vb.net

I have a list box that I only want to appear when there are a certain number of entries in it

```
    if maxentries is not 20 then listbox 1 = ""
    endif
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using immediate if:

```
listBox1.Visible = IIf(listBox1.Items.Count>=20,true,false)
```

Comment: Glad that it work for you @user1556464. Happy coding and GOD bless.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps

```
listBox1.Visible = listBox1.Items.Count >= 20
```

Comment: @user1556464: Why, what didn't work? What is the `DataSource` of the `ListBox`, how are you adding items?

Answer (score 0):

```
If listBox1.Items.Count >= 20 Then
   listBox1.Visible = true
Else
   listBox1.Visible = false
```

Comment: @user1556464: But it's the same as my one liner ;-)